# Spam like answers occuring in the evening (10-11pm Eastern Standard Time USA)

Tags: discussion, spam

I have been flagging multiple answers on the board for the last couple of evenings where a 'new' user (with no reputation) has posted either the question, an answer, a selection of comments, or a combination of the previous.  It is just a text copy with no attempt to format.  I suspect we are beginning to see a deliberate attack on the site.

The problem with these posts is that they mask the real new users whom we want to encourage to participate and learn.   It is a waste of time to open a posting and check the participation of a new user to see if they can be encouraged only to discover it is basically a Denial of Service attack (albeit very slow).

I suspect this is the actions of a single person and I wonder if the moderators can check the logs and see if this traffic is coming from the same IP address.  And if so, then just block it.   And I suggest that the moderators of other stackexchange sites be queried to see this problem is occurring elsewhere.

Comment: Note that blocking IP addresses, _etc._, is managed automatically by the back-end, not by the mods. Flagging as spam is the best way to 'inform' this back-end process: it takes account of the number and rate of spam flags.

Comment: This was also my concern in [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6013/is-there-any-way-to-deal-with-spam-effectively-and-relatively-fast).

Comment: At that time of day i am usually sound asleep, but may i ask one thing: Are the user names *names* or just *userNumber*?

Comment: @Johannes_B They are userNumber with different numbers each time.

Answer (score 21):

This happens occasionally. The [last such attack](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3764/5764) [was around 1.5 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192820/168244) (although it feels like yesterday) and threatened different sites across the entire SE network at different levels of severity. I think the same is happening now, and we might just be a target hit more severely than others.

I suspect the same type of "invasion" is happening, just a little more skilfully; instead of posting watch-NFL-type easy-to-identify nonsensical jibber-jabber, they are now posted a mix-match of question/answer/comments from the site.

With this in mind, we should follow [the same procedure as last year](https://youtu.be/Pn9vPG8s4ss?t=5m1s): Flag as spam, possibly cast a delete vote, consider down-voting and move on. This too shall pass and perhaps the SE spam filters will be improved to thwart such nincompoops... until they strike again with some other witty wizardry.

<sub>The act of dually [flagging as spam and down-voting may be discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193916/168244). However, we're a small yet wide-spread enough community that influx of garbage is quite swiftly taken care of by our janitors.</sub>